# Creating SAPUI5 supported Arrows-Buttons to skip 3,6,9 Months

Tags: javascript, button, datepicker, sapui5

I want to know if there is a way to create SAPUI5 supported Arrow Looking Buttons in order to Skip: 3 Months, 6 Months, 9 Months.

[Something like this but SAPUI5 Supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDEJ0.png)

If there isn't any, any suggestions how would you do it, working within an SAPUI5 Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add buttons and call the [setDateValue](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DateTimeField/methods/setDateValue) method of the [sap.m.DatePicker](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker) ?

Comment: is there a way to shape the Buttons to have this kind of Form?

Comment: Maybe the setBeginIcon and setEndIcon methods? [Link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase/methods/addBeginIcon)